# PHP curl_setopt_array not sending post prams data

Tags: php, curl, php-5.6, php-curl

In PHP 5.6,
When i try to send post data using curl_setopt_array,post data not sending. But the data is sent when i am using curl_setopt

**1. POST data and curl params:**

```
$url = "https://XXXXXXXXXXX/oauth/v2/accessToken";

$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    'code'=>$_REQUEST['code'],
    'redirect_uri'=>$redirect_uri,
    'client_id'=>$client_id,
    'client_secret'=>$client_secret
 );

$header = array('Content-Type: application/ x-www-form-urlencoded');

$options = array( 
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data),
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST=>true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    // CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);
```

**2.here is my "curl_setopt_array" code:**

```
$feed = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
$json = curl_exec($feed);
curl_close($feed);

var_dump( $json);
```

**3.here is my "curl_setopt" code**

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$response = json_decode( $response,true);

var_dump($response);
```

note:
i'm not good in English, written as per my knowledge.

OUTPUT :

for "CURL_SETOPT_ARRAY" code:

string(95) "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"A required parameter \"client_id\" is missing"}"

for "CURL_SETOPT" code:
After json decode:
    array(2) { ["access_token"]=> string(179) "AQWXnJKB5enEyPcqY68ldCUyWayz2LsNXhp-9E-RBaEwGX8EyB5rIDL6YcZh6k_kPT9vJbo_xAQUCeu4hJjeqJTFmTjuFhI3rReHCF4xYBeqGdA7L5_HXSqmdk6oZXtcRSqvCunp2HYsaoLpnCUeFFeYIF5MchaRXl8P_OjXERC3J7XHDU0" ["expires_in"]=> int(5183999) }

Comment: Properly using capital letters or even punctuation in most cases does not require any elaborate English language knowledge...

Comment: What's in your `var_dump`. show us that too

Comment: for "CURL_SETOPT_ARRAY" code : 
    string(95) "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"A required parameter \"client_id\" is missing"}"

Comment: for "CURL_SETOPT" code:


array(2) { ["access_token"]=> string(179) "AQWXnJKB5enEyPcqY68ldCUyWayz2LsNXhp-9E-RBaEwGX8EyB5rIDL6YcZh6k_kPT9vJbo_xAQUCeu4hJjeqJTFmTjuFhI3rReHCF4xYBeqGdA7L5_HXSqmdk6oZXtcRSqvCunp2HYsaoLpnCUeFFeYIF5MchaRXl8P_OjXERC3J7XHDU0" ["expires_in"]=> int(5183999) }

Answer (score 0):

it is possible the API you are interacting with expects JSON instead of URLENCODED data, try replacing `http_build_query` with `json_encode` and let us know if that helped! :)

Comment: No, brother i wasn't work.. but i found the mistake. there is a space between slash and x-www-form-urlencoded.
 **`(application/ x-www-form-urlencoded)`** .
So,I removed the space.then it has to be
 **`(application/x-www-form-urlencoded)`**.
It is working fine now. Anyhow thanks for your effort and reply.